# Comparar si 2 strings tienen alguna character en comun

Tags: javascript, string, regex

tengo dos objetos con keys y quiero comparar una key con otra de otro objeto, si esta contiene algun caracter del string me devuelva true

Por el momento encontre .match y me devuelve true solo si es exactamente igual pero quiero true si tiene alguna letra en comun, por ejemplo si comparo 'lavadora' con 'arbol' me tendria que dar true porque tienen una letra en comun como es la a.

Quiero que usando un filter por ejemplo devolver una copia de `arr` en el que se compare por la key del `arr2` con todas las del `arr` y que se quede solo con las que coincidan

```js
const arr = [
  {
    alt: 'arbol'
  },
  {
    alt: 'astro'
  }
]
const arr2 = [
  {
    alt: 'ar'
  }
]
console.log(arr[0].alt)
console.log(arr2[0].alt)
const found = arr[0].alt.match(arr2[0].alt , "/[abc]+/g");
if(found){
     console.log('is match')
}else {
  console.log('not match')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Más que una expresión regular lo que yo haría sería iterar cada caracter de uno de los **String** para ir preguntando si existe en el otro **String**. Para ello puedes usar un bucle junto con la combinación de la función `includes()`.

```js
const arr = [
  { alt: 'arbol' },
  { alt: 'astro' },
]
const arr2 = [
  { alt: 'ar' },
]
const palabrasCoincidentes = arr.filter((palabra) => compartenCaracter(palabra.alt, arr2[0].alt))

console.log(palabrasCoincidentes)

function compartenCaracter (palabra1, palabra2) {
  let comparte = false

  for (const letra of palabra1) {
    if (palabra2.includes(letra)) {
      comparte = true
    }
  }
  
  return comparte
}
```

**EDIT**

He añadido un filter que lo que hace es recorrer cada palabra de `arr` y preguntar si alguno de sus caracteres está incluido en `arr2[0].alt`, aprovechando la función de comparación de Strings que hice en mi primera respuesta. El resultado es un nuevo array con los objetos que cumplan la coincidencia.

**Referencia:** [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: con un filter se podria hacer similar?

Comment: La función `filter()` se usa para hacer una búsqueda dentro de un array. En tu caso la búsqueda es sobre un **String** por lo que no te valdría.

Comment: en plan, usar filter para filtrar todas las keys que coincidan con la 1 key de arr2

Comment: Pues dependiendo de lo que quieras conseguir. En tu pregunta dices que dadas 2 keys del objeto (dos String) quieres saber si comparten algún caracter entre ellas. Eso es una comparación de 2 String. Si lo que quieres es que la función reciba los arrays y que vaya comparando cada una de las keys entre si hasta que se hayan comparado todas entre todas entonces si que podrías usar un filter.

Comment: justo eso, tengo que actualizar la pregunta

Comment: Añadí una edición a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto sea lo que necesitas, agregue la método startsWith para comparar tipo de letra contiene en la propiedad `alt`

```js
  const arr = [
    {
      alt: "arbol"
    },
    {
      alt: "astro"
    }
  ];

  const arr2 = [
    {
      alt: "ar"
    }
  ];

 const found = arr.filter(({ alt }) => alt.startsWith(arr2[0].alt));

  if (!!found[0]) {
    console.log(`${found[0].alt} is match`);
  } else {
    console.log("not match");
  }
```